# Can't connect Amazon RDS PostgreSQL with codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-rds

I've created a `postgres` sql database with `amazon RDS`. I can access without problem with navicat postgre on my computer, but i can't access with codeigniter 3 on my dedicated server.

I tried to create rules with `amazon RDS`, but it still doesn't work.

I join a configuration of my CI database !! 
The message i get with this configuration is :

`SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired.`

I've spent hours and hours on this problem, i din't understand what is wrong.

I tried to change dbdriver to postgre, but it still doesn't  work :

the error i get with : `postgre` as dbdriver :

```
Message: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: 
                       invalid connection option "pgsql:host"
```

[image: config screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution . 
I had to add a rule to allow my server to access the amazon server.

Here are the setting of the security group i add : 
Inbound - TCP - PORT - the ip of my server XXX.XXX.XXX.XX/32